# Childbrowser plugin location bar

Tags: phonegap-plugins

i I am using a childbroser to show an external page. On android (don't know about IOS)
the top bar is difficult to see (arrows (left) and cross (right) are light on a lightgray background)
does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the images of the arrows with ones more clearer